# Table lines fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

How to i can do the lines for the last item so it wont do this

[This is the picture of my problem in fpdf](http://tinypic.com/r/zl6mop/8)

my picture is in here cause i don't have 10 reputation sorry

This is my code to make the lines for each item
PLease help thanks

> `$i = 0;
>       $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
>       while ($i < $number_of_products)
>       {
>       $pdf->SetX(5);
>       $pdf->MultiCell(200,6,'',1);
>       $i = $i +1;
>   }`

Comment: Is the data in the circled cell meant to be part of another row? Or should it not be there at all?

Comment: no it should be of the one on the top

Comment: is cause one of my fields is long when i call it from the database and goes down with a line instead of just be in that same row #10

Comment: I think this has to do with how the $pdf object works. Check to see how it works. It could be that the table object includes a block for when you use it to list product pricings or other numerical data. If this does exist, then you could try to set it to display nothing, or turn it off altogether. Another possibility is that there is an option you can set to allow the table lines to expand if the text inside them is too big for one line.

Comment: What is the $pdf object you are declaring before the code you have given in the question?

Comment: $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position); this is to set the line vertical

Comment: I think more code can make a little help

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Cell function instead of MultiCell. According to the documentation for fpdf, MultiCell will automatically move to the next cell when the right border is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Use table with multicell to solve the issue of dynamic width and height.And click this link to see the example of plugin [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php).This will be very much useful for dynamic width and height.